# Python Regex is not working for the given pattern

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract a pattern from string using python regex. But it is not working with the below pattern

```
headerRegex = re.compile(r'^[^ ]*\s+\d*') 
        mo = headerRegex.search(string) 
        return mo.group()
```

My requirment is regular expression that should start with anything except white space and followed by one or more whitespace then digits occurence one or more

```
Example
i/p: test  7895  => olp:7895(correct)
i/p:  8545 ==> Not matching
i/p: @#@#  3453 ==>3453
```

May I know what is missing in my regex to implement this requirement?

Comment: Change your `*`s to `+`s.

Comment: Or use `^\S+[^\S\r\n]+\d+$` https://regex101.com/r/IEHGSe/1

Comment: Do you want to extract a pattern or do you want to match a pattern? 
If you want to search a pattern inside a string what do you mean by regex shouldn't start with white space. Please explain.
(or)
 If you want to find if the input matches with the pattern then try
 ```pattern=re.compile('\S+\s+\d+')```
```re.match(pattern,string_to_be_matched)```

Comment: I'm trying to extract the number from the string

Answer (score 1):

In the pattern that you tried, only matching whitespace chars is mandatory, and you might possibly also match only newlines.

Change the quantifiers to + to match 1+ times, and if you don't want to match newlines as well use `[^\S\r\n]+` instead.

If that exact match is only allowed, add an anchor `$` to assert the end of the string, or add `\Z` if there is no newline following allowed.

```
^\S+[^\S\r\n]+\d+$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\S+` Match 1+ times a non whitespace char
- `[^\S\r\n]+` Match 1+ times a whitespace char except newlines
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/J5JX6q/1)